# Undefined reference to '_fdopen' when linking against bzip2 library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, standard-library

I'm new to compiling on linux, so I'm treading on somewhat unfamiliar territory.
I'm using the G++ and GCC compilers on Ubuntu 14.04 .

I'm trying to compile bzip2 (1.0.6) as a shared library and use it in another application.

To build the shared library, I've used:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC \
    -o ./lib/libbzip2.so \
blocksort.c bzip2.c bzlib.c compress.c crctable.c decompress.c huffman.c randtable.c \
    >& compile.log
```

No errors were reported and the .so-file was created successfully.

To build my application and link to the bzip2-library, I've used:

```
g++ -std=c++11 \
    -I ../bzip2-106 \
    main.cpp \
    -L../bzip2-106/lib \
    -o main \
    -lbzip2 \
    >& compile.log
```

This results in the following errors:

```
../bzip2-106/lib/libbzip2.so: undefined reference to `_fdopen'
../bzip2-106/lib/libbzip2.so: undefined reference to `_isatty'
../bzip2-106/lib/libbzip2.so: undefined reference to `_fileno'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I know, fdopen, isatty and fileno are functions from the standard libraries. But if that's the case, shouldn't the compiler automatically link to the appropriate standard libraries? If not, what libraries do I need to link against? What's the significance of the underscore? Does compiling bzip2 as a C-library have anything to do with it?

Comment: You might try adding `-x c` to your invocation of the compiler for `libbzip2.so`. If that's not it, then dump symbols with `nm -g`, run then through `grep` (like `grep fdopen`) and report back.

Comment: Adding '-x c' didn't seem to have any effect. It did find something in the symbol dump, however: http://puu.sh/g7Bdr/f8fd76b023.jpg

Comment: The `U` is undefined (not defined and exported in the text section via `T`; and not defined and private in the text section  via `t`). `man fdopen 3` suggests you need to link with `-lc`.

Comment: Tried linking both the bzip2 library and the main application with -lc, still no difference however.

Comment: can you do ldd libbzip2.so and post the output?

Comment: Here it is: http://puu.sh/g7Cd5/a68278a92a.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No errors were reported because you asked for none.  The leading underscores on the symbols are likely the immediate problem.  bzip2 comes with a Makefile-libbz2_so which one would normally use as the starting point (it does turn on compiler warnings, and sets up dependencies in the shared object).

Leading underscores on Linux are an anomaly -- long ago (pre-ELF), these were common.  But standardization has done away with that.  Whether I compile using the command you have cited, or using the recommended makefile, there are no leading underscores on the external symbols in the shared library.  Rather, "nm" with no options shows (for example, using Ubuntu 14.04)

```
U fchmod@@GLIBC_2.2.5                                          
U fchown@@GLIBC_2.2.5                                          
U fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5                                          
U fdopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5                                          
U ferror@@GLIBC_2.2.5                                          
U fflush@@GLIBC_2.2.5                                          
U fgetc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

As for linking with g++ (the main.cpp is not shown), we would assume that it includes bzlib.h (which does have the expected extern "C" wrapping the C prototypes).

So... we are missing some information.